# error in loading skin in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

I get this error when I load a page that uses a specific skin ,it was working very well befor .

Could Not Load Skin: /Portals/_default/Skins/MM-SubSites-Arb/inner.ascx Error: The ID 'dnnCOPYRIGHT' is already used by another control.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what to look for:  there is more than one control in the inner.ascx file that has an ID attribute of "dnnCOPYRIGHT."

Open the file in a text editor and do a search for "dnnCOPYRIGHT" to find the elements with that ID, and delete all but one of them.

Comment: Or rename/remove the ID without removing the element